# How to make the component to respect column and row Weights?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

```
public class Tester {

    public static class Frame extends JFrame {
        public Frame() {

            // Layout 
            GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout();
            layout.columnWeights=new double[] { 0.5, 0.5 };
            layout.rowWeights=new double[] { 1 };

            // Frame                
            setLayout(layout);
            setSize(500,500);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            // Constraints
            GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            // Panel 1
            JPanel p1=new JPanel();
            p1.setBackground(Color.green);
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=0;
            add(p1,c);

            // Panel 2
            JLabel l1=new JLabel("TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST" +
                                 "TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST");
            l1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            c.gridx=1;
            c.gridy=0;
            add(l1,c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

In this case `l1` takes whole space, I want it to take half, as this one says: 
`layout.columnWeights=new double[] { 0.5, 0.5 };`

I put `c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` because I want: if the frame get resized, i want also the component to be resized, but to take maximum 50% space.

Comment: This is actually how `GridBagLayout` works.  It sees the second column as requiring no space, so supplies the all the available space to the first column.  You could use a `GridLayout` instead

Comment: GridLayout doesn't give me flexibility, I just set 0.5 for this simple example... I am using multiple weights in my case (0.2, 0.5, 0.3)...

There is no way around to achieve this thing?

Comment: Not without putting a component in that column, no...

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Why would you have a frame with a single component and have that component only take up 50% of the space available? That is wasted space. If you plan on having multiple components, then add multiple components to the frame for your testing.

Comment: I edited, i hope now you will understand what i am talking about.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a "filler" component to the "empty" side...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout24 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout24();
    }

    public TestLayout24() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.weightx = 0.5f;
                gbc.weighty = 0.1f;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

                JPanel left = new JPanel();
                left.setBackground(Color.RED);

                JPanel right = new JPanel();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(left, gbc);
                frame.add(right, gbc);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

### Or

You could use `GridLayout` instead...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout24 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout24();
    }

    public TestLayout24() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel left = new JPanel();
                left.setBackground(Color.RED);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.add(left);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figure it out, setting this for the Label, it makes your life much easier!!!!

```
l1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
l1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
```

Thanks for help...